# Enable/Disable text field on checkbox selection ExtJS

Tags: extjs, checkbox

I'm using ExtJS 3 and I need to enable/disable a specific text field when I select/de-select a checkbox, like in the example showed below:

```
{ 
    fieldLabel: 'myCheckBox'
    xtype: 'checkbox',
    name: 'myCheckBox'
},{
    fieldLabel: 'myTextField'
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'myTextField',
    disabled: true
}
```

As I understand it I have to use a listener in 'myCheckBox' like this:

```
listeners: {
   change: function() {

   }
}
```

But I don't know what parameters to pass to my function and how to target '`myTextField`' and `.enable()`  `.disable()`  it. Can you please help me? Thank you very much.

---

Solution based on answers (thank you):

```
listeners: {
     change: function(cb, checked) {
         Ext.getCmp('myTextField').setDisabled(!checked);
 }
 }
```

and added the id tag to the textfield component like this:

```
id: 'myTextField'
```

Comment: Thank you Mark Peters and Ankit for your correct answers. I've used them both in the solution which I've added to the initial question for others with the same question doubt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not sure what to pass as a parameter than Ext.getCmp() gives you the component. It takes id of the component as a parameter. In your case you have to assign id to textfield and can get it on change event as Ext.getCmp('myTextField'). Where myTextField is an id of textfield. Name and Id of a component can be same.

```
listeners: {
 change: function() {
     Ext.getCmp('myTextField').disable();
     //or
     Ext.getCmp('myTextField').enable();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to reference `myTextField`.  The easiest is probably to give the field a [ref](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-ref) (note that this approach does not work in ExtJS 4, where you are better off with a component query):

```
{
    fieldLabel: 'myTextField'
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'myTextField',
    ref: '../myTextField'
    disabled: true
}
```

Setting the ref will cause the textfield component to be referenced in a property of its owner or one of its ancestors.  So then your listener can simply be something like this (the parameters passed to this function are [listed in the doc](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.form.Field-event-change)):

```
change: function(cb, checked) {
    me.myTextField.setDisabled(!checked);
}
```

You might need to tweak the `ref` path depending on your component hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Example:

1. Using setDisabled API:
   theStudentForm.findField('stud_name').setDisabled(true);
2. Using setOpacity API:
   theStudentForm.findField('stud_name').labelEl.setOpacity(1);
3. Using readOnly API:
   theStudentForm.findField('stud_name').setReadOnly(true);